# Ionic not refreshing webpage on revisiting page again on android

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building android app using 'Ionic' framework.In my app, I am using navigation menu and navigating to different screens from side navigation menu.When i first load a page from side menu it loads and call web service that is attached on the controller but when I click again on the same option from menu it is not calling web service from same controller.What I believe is that happening due caching. I don't want my views to be cached because it is preventing my controller from calling web service. In states of route provider I have already declared 'cache' property as false and in meta i am setting 'cache control' to 'no cache' but still the same behavior. My question is if I am on a state called 'about us' and from navigation menu if i select same option 'about us' how to reinitialize the same controller. Currently it does not reload controller.

Comment: `It's unclear what you're asking` Please have a look at [ask] and provide [mcve]. How can we solve your problem as you haven't posted single line of code? Please put `<space>` after `.`s as it's easier to read then.

Comment: I think you have set `cache-view` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Add this in app config

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

`$ionicConfigProvider` dependency in config.